# What could cause inconsistent Firestore reads immediately after a transaction?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I'm reading some documents immediately after a Firestore transaction successfully updates one and creates another, but observing that I'm getting the pre-update and pre-creation (exists==false) snapshots of these documents. My understanding is that Firestore in Native mode guarantees strong consistency, so this shouldn't be possible.

If I introduce a 1 second delay between my transaction and the subsequent reads, I get the versions of the documents consistent with the completed transaction. These results seem to be fairly reliably reproducible. What could be causing this "delayed consistency" behavior? I am awaiting completion of the transaction before reading the documents. The actual execution of the Cloud Functions doesn't affect the expected outcomes (e.g. doesn't delete the created document).

I'm using Flutter with Cloud Firestore in Native mode and onCreate/onUpdate (1st gen) triggers for Cloud Functions.

A simple example/test-case without the triggers gives back the expected documents when read immediately after the transaction completes:

```
final ref1 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('Parents/parent1');
final ref2 = FirebaseFirestore.instance.doc('Children/child1');
await FirebaseFirestore.instance.runTransaction((transaction) async {
  final doc1 = await transaction.get(ref1);
  final doc2data = { 'value': doc1.data()!['value'], };

  transaction.update(ref1, {
    'children': FieldValue.arrayUnion(['child1']),
  });
  transaction.set(ref2, doc2data);
});
final doc1 = await ref1.get();
debugPrint('doc1:children: ${doc1.data()?['children']}');
final doc2 = await ref2.get();
debugPrint('doc2.exists: ${doc2.exists}');
```

This behaves as expected, with output like:

```
flutter: doc1:children: [child1]
flutter: doc2.exists: true
```

Comment: I'm not sure how Cloud Function are involved in the problem. Can you explain that part? Unless of course you can reproduce with only the Flutter code you shared, in which case it's probably better to remove mention of Cloud Functions. Also see: [how to create a minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks for your response, @FrankvanPuffelen ! Perhaps the enqueuing of the Cloud Functions based on Firestore triggers must complete before the new document snapshot is readable? E.g. the event is written as part of an adjunct transaction. My understanding is that Firestore reads should be consistent as soon as a transaction is completed, so the fact that I'm getting inconsistent reads at all is surprising.

Comment: I tried listening to the two documents after the transaction to get a better sense of the behavior. I see that in most cases I first get a snapshot representative of the pre-transaction state, and then within ~0.03 seconds get another snapshot reflecting the transaction.